# Image not displaying in datagridview column in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewimagecolumn

I have the following code that I want to use to display an image in a DataGridView cell:

```
dgvInventory.Item(7, i).Value = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("picture")
```

But instead of displaying the required image, it shows `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in the cell.

Please note that the DataGridView table was created at run time, so I know I am supposed to change the column property to be an `DataGridViewImageColumn` but I just could not figure out how to.

Thanks in advance

Please I really need help with this.

**Below is the Complete code**

```
con.Open()
tables.Clear()
dgvInventory.DataSource = tables
dgvInventory.DataSource = Nothing

sql = "SELECT ItemID, itemname, status, ''  FROM [" & InventoryTable & "]"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, InventoryTable)
con.Close() 

'This Loads Records into DataGrid
Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
source1.DataSource = view
dgvInventory.DataSource = view
dgvInventory.AllowUserToAddRows = False

For i = 0 To dgvInventory.RowCount - 1
   If dgvInventory.Item(2, i).Value = 1 then
     dgvInventory.Item(3, i).Value = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("picture")
   Else
     dgvInventory.Item(3, i).Value = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("picture1")
   End If
Next

dgvInventory.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
dgvInventory.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Item / Product / Service"
dgvInventory.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Status"
dgvInventory.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Icon"

dgvInventory.Columns(0).Width = 100
dgvInventory.Columns(1).Width = 300
dgvInventory.Columns(2).Width = 100
dgvInventory.Columns(3).Width = 100

dgvInventory.ClearSelection()
```

Comment: Post te code you're using to generate your DataGridView and the nature of its DataSource. Since you can create a new `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`, you can also create a new `DataGridViewImageColumn`, the initialization method doesn't change (for a default object). Btw, when you generate Images from the Resources, assign the Images to Bitmap objects then assign a Bitmap to a Control's property. Dispose of these Bitmap objects when not needed anymore (when you change a Control's Property or the Parent Form closes).

Comment: Addition to Jimi's comment, when you create the new `DataGridViewImageColumn`, set it's `DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Nothing`, and handle the `RowsAdded` event of the `DGV` to set the required image for each row. Also if you want to get rid of the last row's default `null` image, in the same event, check `If e.RowIndex = 0 Then` ... set the value of the image cell to `Nothing`. Good luck.

Comment: @JQSOFT  Well, you can set the `DataGridViewImageColumn.CellTemplate` using a custom `DataGridViewImageCell`, where you override `DefaultNewRowValue`, setting it to `new Bitmap(1,1)` (or a custom Bitmap of choice, of course) in the `DataGridViewImageCell` constructor (since it's a getter-only property).

Comment: @Jimi True true, I'd use this approach.

Comment: I have edited the question to show the code as requested

Comment: **Please note:** instead of displaying the required image (picture / picture1) which is based on a condition , it writes ```System.Drawing.Bitmap```  in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting something like:

[image: DataGridView with one of the columns having the text Syste.Drawing.Bitmap in each row]

That's because you are getting what the `ToString` function returns for an instance of a `Bitmap` type to be displayed in a default `DataGridViewTextBoxCell`. Note that the *icon* is not a part of your `DataTable`, it's just an image from your resources.

Instead, add a new `DataGridViewImageColumn` after setting the `DataSource` property of the DGV. Please consider the following example:

```
'Class level variables
Private bmp1 As New Bitmap(My.Resources.picture)
Private bmp2 As New Bitmap(My.Resources.picture1)
```

In a method that calls and displays the data, replace this with your actual data source.

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID"))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Item"))
dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Status"))

For i As Integer = 1 To 10
    dt.Rows.Add(i, $"Item {i}", $"Status {i}")
Next

With dgvInventory
    .Clear()
    .DataSource = Nothing
    .DataSource = dt
    .Columns("Item").HeaderText = "Item / Product / Service"
End With

Dim imageColIndex As Integer = dgvInventory.Columns.Count
Dim imgCol As New DataGridViewImageColumn(False) With {
    .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewImageCell() With {
        .Style = New DataGridViewCellStyle() With {
            .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        }
    },
    .DisplayIndex = imageColIndex,
    .Image = Nothing,
    .Name = "Image",
    .HeaderText = "Image",
    .Width = CInt(dgvInventory.RowTemplate.Height * 1.5),
    .DefaultCellStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle() With {.NullValue = Nothing}
}

AddHandler dgvInventory.CellFormatting,
    Sub(obj, arg)
        If arg.ColumnIndex = imageColIndex Then
            arg.Value = If(arg.RowIndex Mod 2 = 0, bmp1, bmp2)
        End If
    End Sub

dgvInventory.Columns.Insert(imageColIndex, imgCol)
```

Where `imageColIndex` is the index of the image column.

Don't forget to clean up in the Form.Closing event:

```
bmp1?.Dispose()
bmp2?.Dispose()
```

and you will get something like:

[image: DataGridView with one of the columns showing an appropriate icon in each row]

Note that you don't need to add columns at design time: you can edit the columns' properties after binding a `DataTable`, `DataView`, `BindingSource`, etc., to your DGV.

**Implementing that in your code:**

```vb
tables.Clear()
con.Open()
sql = "SELECT ItemID, itemname, status, ''  FROM [" & InventoryTable & "]"
da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
da.Fill(ds, InventoryTable)
con.Close()
con.Dispose()

Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
source1.DataSource = view

With dgvInventory
    .Columns.Clear()
    .DataSource = Nothing
    .DataSource = view
    .Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
    .Columns(0).Width = 100
    .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Item / Product / Service"
    .Columns(1).Width = 300
    .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Status"
    .Columns(2).Width = 100
End With

Dim imageColIndex As Integer = dgvInventory.Columns.Count
Dim imgCol As New DataGridViewImageColumn(False) With {
    .CellTemplate = New DataGridViewImageCell() With {
    .Style = New DataGridViewCellStyle() With {
    .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
}
},
.DisplayIndex = imageColIndex,
.Image = Nothing,
.Name = "Icon",
.HeaderText = "Icon",
.Width = CInt(dgvInventory.RowTemplate.Height * 1.5),
.DefaultCellStyle = New DataGridViewCellStyle() With {.NullValue = Nothing}
}

AddHandler dgvInventory.CellFormatting,
    Sub(obj, arg)
        If arg.ColumnIndex = imageColIndex Then
            Dim status As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(
            DirectCast(obj, DataGridView).Item(2, arg.RowIndex).Value)

            arg.Value = If(status = 1, bmp1, bmp2)
        End If
    End Sub

dgvInventory.Columns.Insert(imageColIndex, imgCol)
dgvInventory.ClearSelection()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203932/discussion-on-answer-by-jqsoft-image-not-displaying-in-datagridview-column-in-vb).