# VB.NET: Convert a text column in datagridview to image column and set icon according to text

Tags: vb.net, replace, datagridview, icons

I VB.net, i have a datagridview, that shows some results of a database query. To generate it, i executed some sql query and wrote the data to a datatable. This table is then linked to the dgview

```
dg_data.DataSource = SqlData.DefaultView
```

Now one column can contain certain (fixed and predefined) characters describing a certain status of events that are handled with my app. I would like to replace these characters with more intuitive icons.

I managed to get that working but only in a new further column (12) containing an image according to another columns (11) code character. However, i want to REPLACE the column with that char and only show the image. This is what i have:

```
    'Add new image column:
            Dim imgcol As New DataGridViewImageColumn()
            dg_data.Columns.Add(imgcol)
            imgcol.HeaderText = "Status"
            imgcol.Name = "img"
            imgcol.DataPropertyName = "img"
            With dg_data
                .Columns("img").DisplayIndex = 12
                .Columns("img").Width = 20
            End With

' Load images from Resources    
            Dim report_filed As Image = My.Resources.report_filed
            Dim report_due As Image = My.Resources.noreport
            Dim attention As Image = My.Resources.attention
    
' Assign correct icon for certain character in status column (example for "!")
            For i As Integer = 0 To SqlData.Rows.Count - 1
                If dg_data.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value.ToString = "!" Then
                    dg_data.Rows(i).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.attention
                Else
                    dg_data.Rows(i).Cells("img").Value = My.Resources.report_filed
                End If
            Next i
```

One could of cource just discard column 11 afterwards using

```
  dg_data.Columns(11).Visible = False
```

but i am looking for a more elegant solution here, e.g.

```
Convert column 11 from to to img, replace "!" with image a, "c" with image "b" and so on.
```

Any hints for me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Firstly, don't add image column in code. Add it in the designer. [Here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?541476-NET) is an example of doing that with a combo box column. The principle is exactly the same with an image column, with just a few details changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59238470/10216583