# Visual Basic - Default null image in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to replace the default image of an image column in the datagridview
I'm talking about this icon:

[image]

I should clarify that the datagridview is initially empty, and the user adds rows themselves or loads the cells from file.

I feel like I've searched about every thread and even asked chatgpt but I cant get a clear answer. I also tried setting the image property to my png but that does nothing (even though visual studio suggests the image property sets the default image, strange...).

All I'm trying to do is replace that ugly X with either an empty cell or a custom png. Any help would be appreciated

I have tried to use `CellFormatting` and that did work by inserting a transparent png I made into the rows of that column. However I have a function to allow the user to add their own images and this method doesn't seem to allow it. The image remains the default png. Here's is the code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs)
 If e.ColumnIndex = dataGridView1.Columns("Image").Index Then
        Dim customImage As Image = my.resources.dgvnull
        e.Value = my.resources.dgvnull
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: have a look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232259/image-not-displaying-in-datagridview-column-in-vb-net

Comment: This is very dangerous piece of code. Every time you get an image from resources, you get a **new** instance. Doing this in the `CellFormatting` event which fires for each cell in the grid floods the memory with _zombie_ objects. _Memory leak_ on other words. Just handle the `Load` event and set the style's `NullValue` property of that column to `Nothing` or an image of your choice. dataGridView1.Columns("Image").DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = my.resources.dgvnull`.

Comment: dr.null This DOES work great but it doesnt apply the null image to the new row, only the added rows and the ones that already exist. So basicaly the last row in my datagrid still has the X image.

Comment: Please `@UserName` to page a user. Yes, if you have the `AllowUserToAddRows` property set to `True`. For that new row, you need to set the `Value` property of the image cell to `Nothing`. Implement the grid's `RowsAdded` event to do so. `If e.RowIndex = DataGridView1.NewRowIndex Then DataGridView1(yourImageColumnIndexOrName, e.RowIndex).Value = Nothing`.